# 2 dns for a site + check this dns

Tags: internal-dns, dns-zone, dns-hosting

I noticed something when I checked the dns of this site
What is this for?

```
https://intodns.com/ir-seda.ir
```

Please, someone explain what this is for?
See the photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG49l.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? What is unclear?

Comment: i think i got the point - the dns is false, someone changed afterwards the DNS records for the DNS server to the same ip

Comment: @vidarlo Look at the picture...the top and bottom are different, why?

Comment: Because they're configured differently. Your NS reports a different NS than the parent.

Comment: @vidarlo This is not for me. Please send me the tutorial link

Comment: Requests for learning material recommendations are off-topic here. We expect you actually *know what you are doing*, which means *know how to read related documents* (RFCs in this case) and get all the necessary information from these.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is explained in the picture. The *parent zone* nameserver has the following delegation records regarding your domain `ir-seda.ir` (in the zone `.ir`):

```
ir-seda.ir. 1440 NS ns6.sitfa.ir.
ir-seda.ir. 1440 NS ns8.sitfa.ir.
```

However, these DNS servers contain the following NS records instead (in the zone `ir-seda.ir`):

```
ir-seda.ir. 86400 NS ns5.sepahanserver.com.
ir-seda.ir. 86400 NS ns6.sepahanserver.com.
```

This is not very good. Although all four names `ns6.sitfa.ir`, `ns8.sitfa.ir`, `ns5.sepahanserver.com` and `ns6.sepahanserver.com` resolve into the same IP 46.4.68.24, the [RFC 1912](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1912#section-2.8) suggests that both NS records specified in the delegation records in the parent zone and NS records specified within the zone itself should be the same:

> Make sure your parent domain has the same NS records for your zone as you do.

You need to either change your delegation to point to `ns5.sepahanserver.com.` and `ns6.sepahanserver.com.` in the registrar panel, *or* change your zone to list `ns6.sitfa.ir.` and `ns8.sitfa.ir.` as nameservers, to have match.

---

What bothers me even more, is that *both* nameservers for the zone point to the same IP address. It shouldn't be like that. You should have at least two separate nameservers accessible and working independently, which implies they must have different public IP addresses. The same section of RFC1912 (link is above) covers this too:

> You are required to have at least two nameservers for every domain, though more is preferred. Have secondaries outside your network.

Comment: This is not for me. I am also surprised for this We are facing extensive filtering in Iran - It means that the government has imposed censorship and restrictions... except for a few sites such as Google and famous sites, we cant connect to other sites that have servers outside of Iran. 

So that the sites that are on servers outside of Iran are loaded very slowly but , ir-seda.ir > Although this site is located on a server outside of Iran (Germany), it loads quickly. I wanted to know what method he used, did he make a tunnel?

Comment: The issue we are discussing here has nothing to do with censorship and tunnels. This is solely about wrong DNS configuration. If you want to know something about why this site is fast, better ask exactly *that*, and do it *in the separate question*. Probably SuperUser is better place to ask, since ServerFault is not even suitable for that kind of questions.

Comment: I mean, maybe with this method they bypassed this limitation

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, no idea. Ask a separate question, with proper tags, and specify what exactly you want to know. Maybe someone who knows more about Iranian censorship will be able to spot it and answer. This question is asked like it's about DNS issue so there is little chance a censorship specialist will be attracted to it, and it's even less chance that they will read through all the comments.